# Twilio live transfers

Tags: javascript, php, rest, twilio, transfer

This may have been asked multiple times before but I obviously am not grokking any of the answers so i am asking again.

I have a system in Twilio that can make and receive calls. I am using Javascript to accept/reject/make calls that I found in the example from Twilio (With a few very minor and mainly cosmetic alterations).

When a person calls into my test company, the call is sent to a twiml bin that basically does a dial of two clients (I have two test users, each with a separate number, that get the possibility to take the call using a dial with two client nodes). All of that works well.

But now, I want to have a person that accepts that call to transfer it to another person. I'd love it to be any number but I'd even be okay if I could only transfer to people defined in the twilio system... I basically don't care right now. A transfer to anyone or even a robot voice would be something I'd cling to as hope.

Every single example seems to indicate that I'd simply do a call to to a PHP code that would create a rest client and then call an Update method to send it to a different twiml. Great.

Problem : There is no such thing as a Services_Twilio_Rest_Client. I've tried every iteration of that I can think of and there is just no class I can create that will work.

Obviously this is possible. But I have now hit my head on this for roughly a week straight, have lost my patience and am getting ready to rip my hair out. Can someone walk me through the process of doing this?

Comment: Big wall of text. What's your actual question summed up in about 15 words?

Comment: How do I transfer a live call? Every example I have seen or have received from twilio simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt the Twilio PHP SDK the rest client itself? E.g.

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php#send-an-sms

References:

`$client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);`

It looks like you want to update the call state, which Twilio has an example of here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state

You can change your language to PHP to see the exact usage pattern.

Comment: If it is then it does not have the "Update" method that the twilio examples seem to think exist...

Comment: @user2965514 i updated my answer. Looks like you want to update the call state

Comment: I actually have based my attempts around the PHP version of that. It honestly doesn't work. All it accomplishes is a series of errors that say that the class does not exist.

Comment: So I dont understand your actual problem. First you say you cannot find some PHP class. Then you say you found the PHP class but ... what? So you do call the `update` method but it doesnt work?

Comment: No - the class does not exist. I have a nice look at the classes in the REST directory on the server. Not a single one of them is "Client". I go from "Account" all the way to "UsageTriggers" without a single mention of a "Client". And when I think that perhaps it is part of the instantiated REST stuff and just say that I want to create a new rest client, it says "Fatal error: Class 'Services_Twilio_Rest_Client' not found in /home/timothy/sites/next-call/application/controllers/tools.php on line 322"

Comment: Here is the client: `https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/Twilio/Rest/Client.php` right under the `Rest` directory. Perhaps you're using a different version of the SDK? I looks like there are differences between 4.x and 5.x but mainly around autoload and class discovery/instantiation.

Comment: I got into it and, yeah, this SDK is totally different from the one I have... That explains A LOT!